# how do i scroll the elements with the background in this situation?

Tags: python, pygame

I don't know which one, it could be a command to scroll the item class along with the background.  so could you help me find a command to move more than one class

```
class item(object):


    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.end = end
        self.path = [self.x, self.end]
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.vel = 3
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)


    def draw(self,win):
        win.blit(d, (self.x,self.y))
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2)


if keys[pygame.K_d] or keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            man.x += man.vel
            man.left = False
            man.right = True
            man.up = False
            man.down = False

            if man.x > 1750:
                background.scroll(-5,0)
                man.x = 1750
```

Comment: there is no special command to scroll background and other elements - you have to write own function to do this. In some places it is called "camera" or "viewport". You keep offset in global variable and you add it to position when you draw every element.

Comment: eventually you can draw all in normal way but on bigger surface and later you display this surface with some offset - and this way all will scroll together.

Comment: Could you show the entire file? Will help out a ton.

Comment: @BlueStaggo This is a bad advise. The question has to contain a [**Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but  neither the complet application nor a link to an off-site resource.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special command to scroll background and other elements at once. You have to write code which remeber player move (ie. offset_x, offset_y)

```
player.move(speed_x, speed_y)

offset_x -= speed_x
offset_y -= speed_y
```

or version which always keep player in center

```
player.move(speed_x, speed_y)

offset_x = screen_rect.centerx - player.rect.centerx
offset_y = screen_rect.centery - player.rect.centery
```

and later you use it when you draw all object

```
screen.fill(BLACK)

background.draw(screen, offset_x, offset_y)

object1.draw(screen, offset_x, offset_y)
object2.draw(screen, offset_x, offset_y)

player.draw(screen, offset_x, offset_y)
```

and it uses offset only to calculate position to draw but it doesn't change original position

```
def draw(self, surface, offset_x=0, offset_y=0):
    # don't change original `self.rect`

    rect = self.rect.move(offset_x, offset_y)

    surface.blit(self.image, rect)
```

---

Minima working example. Use `WASD` to move object and `SPACE` to turn on/off scrolling.

Code scroll always - it doesn't check if player is near map's border because it need extra code to stop scrolling or use `if` which check player position before changing offset or skiping offset.

```
pygame.display.flip()

import pygame
import random

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 25

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

GRAY  = (128, 128, 128)

RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)

# --- classes --- (CamelCaseNames)

class Item(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((width, height)).convert()
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(centerx=x, centery=y)
        
    def update(self):
        pass
    
    def move(self, speed_x=0, speed_y=0):
        self.rect.move_ip(speed_x, speed_y)

    def draw(self, surface, offset_x=0, offset_y=0):
        # don't change original `self.rect`
        rect = self.rect.move(offset_x, offset_y)
        surface.blit(self.image, rect)

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

background = Item(screen_rect.centerx, screen_rect.centery, 600, 400, GREEN)

player = Item(screen_rect.centerx, screen_rect.centery, 50, 50, GRAY)

object1 = Item(200 , 200, 50, 50, RED)
object2 = Item(600 , 400, 50, 50, BLUE)
# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

use_offset = False

offset_x = 0
offset_y = 0

speed_x = 0
speed_y = 0

running = True
while running:

    # --- events ---
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            # turn on/off scrolling
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                use_offset = not use_offset

    # A = move left, D = move right
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_a]:
        speed_x = -5
    elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_d]:
        speed_x = 5
    else:
        speed_x = 0

    # W = move up, S = move down
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w]:
        speed_y = -5
    elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_s]:
        speed_y = 5
    else:
        speed_y = 0

    # --- changes/moves/updates ---

    # first move, later get offset    
    player.move(speed_x, speed_y)

    if use_offset:           
        offset_x -= speed_x
        offset_y -= speed_y
    
    #if use_offset:           
    #    offset_x = screen_rect.centerx - player.rect.centerx
    #    offset_y = screen_rect.centery - player.rect.centery
    #else:
    #    offset_x = 0
    #    offset_y = 0

    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    
    background.draw(screen, offset_x, offset_y)
    
    object1.draw(screen, offset_x, offset_y)
    object2.draw(screen, offset_x, offset_y)
    
    player.draw(screen, offset_x, offset_y)
    
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- FPS ---

    ms = clock.tick(FPS)
    #pygame.display.set_caption('{}ms'.format(ms)) # 40ms for 25FPS, 16ms for 60FPS
    
    #fps = clock.get_fps()
    #pygame.display.set_caption('FPS: {}'.format(fps))
    
# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version without `Rect()`, `rect.move()`, `rect.move_ip()`, `rect.centerx`, `rect.centery`

```
import pygame
import random

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 25

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

GRAY  = (128, 128, 128)

RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)

# --- classes --- (CamelCaseNames)

class Item:

    def __init__(self, centerx, centery, width, height, color):
        self.x = centerx - width//2
        self.y = centery - height//2
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((width, height)).convert()
        self.image.fill(color)

        #self.rect = self.image.get_rect(centerx=centerx, centery=centery)

    def update(self):
        pass

    def move(self, speed_x=0, speed_y=0):
        self.x += speed_x
        self.y += speed_y
        #self.rect.move_ip(speed_x, speed_y)

    def draw(self, surface, offset_x=0, offset_y=0):
        # don't change original `self.x, self.y`
        x = self.x + offset_x
        y = self.y + offset_y
        surface.blit(self.image, (x,y))

        # don't change original `self.rect`
        #rect = self.rect.move(offset_x, offset_y)
        #surface.blit(self.image, rect)

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

background = Item(screen_rect.centerx, screen_rect.centery, 600, 400, GREEN)

player = Item(screen_rect.centerx, screen_rect.centery, 50, 50, GRAY)

object1 = Item(200 , 200, 50, 50, RED)
object2 = Item(600 , 400, 50, 50, BLUE)
# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

use_offset = True

offset_x = 0
offset_y = 0

speed_x = 0
speed_y = 0

running = True
while running:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            # turn on/off scrolling
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                use_offset = not use_offset

    # A = move left, D = move right
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_a]:
        speed_x = -5
    elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_d]:
        speed_x = 5
    else:
        speed_x = 0

    # W = move up, S = move down
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w]:
        speed_y = -5
    elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_s]:
        speed_y = 5
    else:
        speed_y = 0

    # --- changes/moves/updates ---

    # first move, later get offset
    player.move(speed_x, speed_y)

    #if use_offset:
    #    offset_x -= speed_x
    #    offset_y -= speed_y

    if use_offset:
    #    #offset_x = screen_rect.centerx - player.rect.centerx
    #    #offset_y = screen_rect.centery - player.rect.centery
        offset_x = screen_rect.centerx - (player.x + player.width//2)
        offset_y = screen_rect.centery - (player.y + player.height//2)
    else:
        offset_x = 0
        offset_y = 0

    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    background.draw(screen, offset_x, offset_y)

    object1.draw(screen, offset_x, offset_y)
    object2.draw(screen, offset_x, offset_y)

    player.draw(screen, offset_x, offset_y)

    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- FPS ---

    ms = clock.tick(FPS)
    #pygame.display.set_caption('{}ms'.format(ms)) # 40ms for 25FPS, 16ms for 60FPS

    #fps = clock.get_fps()
    #pygame.display.set_caption('FPS: {}'.format(fps))

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: the problem is that, i have class for player, what can i do?

Comment: change this class

Comment: I did, but it gives me the error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'move_ip'

Comment: because you don't use `pygame.Rect()` to keep position and size. If you keep postion in `tuple` then you need normal  method to change it `var = (var[0] + speed_x, var[1] + speed_y)`

Comment: can you explain better?

Comment: pygame has special class to keep position and size `rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)` and when you use it then you can use its special functions `rect.move()`, `rect.clamp(screen_rect)` (to keep inside `screen` or `map`) and also to check collisions `rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)` (to check if button was clicked)` , `rect.colliderect(enemy_rect)` (to check if player collide with enemy). BUT you don't use [pygame.Rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) then you have to make all calculations on your own .

Comment: and you can use this `rect` to draw object `blit(image, rect)`. If you will use class [pygame.sprite.Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) then it has also function to collide with groups of objectes and it also need `self.rect` for this. SO it is more useful to use `self.rect` instead of  `self.x`, `self.y`, `self.width`, `self.height`. It has also `self.rect.center` to get center of item - and you can use it with `other_rect.center` to center ie. text on button, or item on screen. It has also `rect.right`  instead of `x+width`, and `rect.botton` instead of `y+height`

Comment: @maomao I don't know - if you don't use `Rect` then it may need a lot changes.

Comment: okay so i should delete self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height and just create self.rect, which i already have but acts as a hitbox to be able to create collisions.  besides, the character is animated, I don't know if anything changes.

Comment: if you don't change it then use `x,y` and add `offset_x`, `offset_y` when you draw it -  in your situation it can be `win.blit(d, (self.x+offset_x, self.y+offset_y))` and `self.hitbox = (self.x + 17 + offset_x, self.y + 2 + offset_y, 31, 57)` , and then same in any other `blit()` and `draw()` which you have in code.

Comment: doing so how do i replace speedx, speedy in player.move?

Comment: normally you have to do it manuallly with your `x`, `y` - `man.x += speedx`  `man.y += speedy`

Comment: keeps giving me the "move_ip has no attribute tuple" error from before

Comment: you don't use `Rect(x, y)` but normal tuple `(x,y)` so you can't use `move_ip(speedx, speedy)` which works ONLY with `Rect` - you have to use normal `man.x += speedx, man.y += speedy` .

Comment: it seems `Rect()` is too big problem for you - so I created version without `Rect()`

Comment: ok the camera now works, but the player does not show the previously set side animation sprites.  and the screen in which it moves, once exceeded a certain height and width, begins to show many you want the same sprite as the player, eliminating itself when you return to the small functional area

Comment: if you vuoi i share the code, maybe it's easier to understand

Comment: do you have it on GitHub or other portal ? Send link or code on furas@tlen.pl

Comment: did you receive it?

Comment: minimal working code (with images) on GitHub https://github.com/furas/pygame-example-1

Comment: uh, thanks, one last question, how do i get the character to move  diagonale too? besides, the rescue system no longer works

Comment: when I check keys `A,D` and later `W,S` I use `elif` instead of `if` and now it doesn't move diagonal - I didn't have animation for diagonal move. But If you use again `if` instead of `elif` then it should move diagonal

Comment: I changed code in repo - now it moves diagonal - search word `diagonal` in file `main-mod.py`

Comment: if `rescue system` means 'saving to pickle' then I didn't test it before. I needs `player.rect.x` `player.rect.y` instead of `player.x`, `player.y`. I changed it in repo

Comment: mh thanks again, but how come the player's speed increases if I go diagonally?

Comment: you don't make single direct diagonal move but two moves: vertical+horizontal - and every move changes `self.walk_count += 1` so animation moves faster. Second: when you move vertically 9 pixel and horizontally 9 pixels then diagonally you move almost 13 pixels so it can looks like it moves faster. ([Pythagorean_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) - `a**2 + b**2 = c**2` which gives `9**2 + 9**2 = 12.7279**2`). You have to add code which moves only diagonally. And this is why I used `elif` instead of `if` to skip diagonal moves because it need more code.

Comment: can you help me? if it is not a problem

Comment: and then how can I set up a bigger screen, so more background files?

Comment: for diagonal you will have to add something like `if up and right : .. code for angle 45 ..` and then you can use `sin()`, `cos()` to calculate `vel_x, vel_y` which give `x**2 + y**2 = 9**2` and then it will move diagonally `vel = 9` pixels. For angle 45 it will be `vel_x = 9 * math.sin(math.radians(45))` and `vel_x = 9 * math.sin(math.radians(45))
` OR you can use `pygame` for this  - `vel = pygame.math.Vector2((9,0))` and `vel_x, vel_y = vel.rotate(45)`

Comment: instead for the change of background?

Comment: moreover, the character during the walk shows only 5 frames out of 8 even making the necessary changes

Comment: if you move diagonal then you have to skip other moves which also use `self.walk_count += 1` and it can create wrong animation. You could alos use `print()` to see values in variable and which part of code is executed - it helps to see where is the problem. It is called "print debuging"

Comment: I don't mean diagonally any direction I walk shows only 5 frames

Comment: do you use my code ? I created animation for 4 frames and I used smaller values in loops which create aniamtion. You have to learn to debug code to find out wher can be the problem.

Comment: ok now, work, but for the background, what if i wanted to create a bigger game screen and put lots of background files?

Comment: it doesn't matter how many files you have - you can change class `Background` so it get filename as argument and create many items `bg1 = Background(..., file1)`,  `bg1 = Background(..., file1)`, etc. or even better keep them on list `all_bg = [Background(..., file1), Background(..., file2), ...]` and then you can use `for`-loop to draw it. But if elements don't change on background then you could draw all files on one `Surface()` and later use only this `Surface()` as background.

Comment: if you need map/background bigger screen/window then create variables `SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGTH` (to set windows size and calculuate `offset`)and `MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT` to check if player doesn't leave map.

Comment: sorry, can you give an example?

Comment: what example ? For many background files? You have similar example with `Chest` and `all_chests` in code.

Comment: if you want to draw all on one [Surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) then you work similar to old code - your `win` is also `Surface`, `surface = pygame.Surface(width, height)` , `surface.blit(image, rect)` `pygame.draw.rect(surface,...)`, and later `win.blit(surface, (0,0))`

Comment: done, but how do I change the speed of the player instead? because even raising self.vel in the player and background class does not change the speed

Comment: i don't know if I use `self.vel` in code - I could use directly value `6`. I say again: debug code to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed.

Comment: I test my code and when I change `vel` then it moves faster. And `background` doesn't need `vel` - it doesn't move.

Comment: yes, in fact, you had written in the parental description the value of vel now works for me too, thanks